# Predefining list capacity

Tags: c#, performance, generics

To prevent many re-allocations I have something like this in my code:

```
List<T> result = new List<T>(100);
```

Do I need to call `TrimExcess` before I return the new list or not?

```
result.TrimExcess();
return result;
```

The aim is to make the allocations quicker for the first 100 items, for example. Is this the correct way of doing this or do I need to do anything else?

Comment: Do you have a performance problem when you don't specify the capacity? I am asking, because it looks a lot like **premature optimization**.

Comment: @Daniel Hilgarth, it is premature optimization. The code in question is involved with database work which will more often return more than 10 objects. Therefore, I assume pre-allocation will improve performance.

Comment: @SBlackler, premature optimization meas that you are optimizing when it's not necessary. In doing so, you not only waste your time on things you shouldn't care about (unless you really know you should). And you also make the code unnecessarily complex and harder to maintain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By defining the initail capacity, you did the necessary optimization.
If you the call the `TrimExcess()` method you might cause more allocation work than you really want.

The [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms132207.aspx) for `TrimExcess()` says:

> The cost of reallocating and copying a large List can be
>   considerable, however, so the TrimExcess method does nothing if the
>   list is at more than 90 percent of capacity

What I understand of this is that you might not even change anything on your list with that call.
This looks to me that you really do not gain much with it.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to trim.  The list keeps track of how many items have actually been added, which is different than the initial capacity, which is simply a pre-allocation.

Answer (score 1):

its ok ..

if you dont intend to add more items then you can leave it like you wrote.

Answer (score 1):

If your application is using a lot of memory or more than it should then I would call TrimExcess() but it's probably not worth it unless the list contains very little items like less than 30 or so, even then you probably can just leave it as is. But yes if you want allocation to be faster for the first 100 then make the initial size 100 or even larger if you know you're going to be adding more than 100 items.

Answer (score -1):

Let's make it clear, doing so will not reserve memory for allocation of 100 T but just for 100 'pointer' to T.  So it is ok but probably does not help a lot.

Comment: @svick, In this case, `T` would always be a custom defined class. But does it matter if it is a value type?

Comment: @SBlackler, it matters, because it would make this answer incorrect. If `T` were a value type, the allocation would not be 100 references to `T`, but 100 `T`s directly.

Comment: @svick: are you sure ? what happend if (i being an int) when you do myList.Add(i) then ? Doesn't that create a copy of i ? What would be the benefit of reserving 100 int

Comment: @VdesmedT, adding to a `List<int>` just copies the integer to the internal array. The benefit of reserving 100 integers is that you don't have to reallocate the internal array to make it bigger. That's the same with a value type or a reference type.